# dirichlet density function returning values > 1.0

Tags: r, distributions, probability, density-function, dirichlet-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Probability distribution value exceeding 1 is OK?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok)

I'm comparing results given by [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658866/calculating-pdf-of-dirichlet-distribution-in-python) and that from the gtool library in R, of the Dirichlet density function.

With the following input parameters I get a value > 1. 
Wasn't this a density function? What does it mean that it is greater than 1? Shouldn't it always be in [0,1]?

```
x's: [0.50943396226415094, 0.33962264150943394, 0.11320754716981132, 0.037735849056603772]
alpha's: [0.50294170013982564, 0.38208148445979651, 0.15674706531364499, 0.094593027999751528]
======> variant 1 :  1.27118592142 
======> variant 2 :  1.271186
```